# My css file changes are only applying to index.html and not to other html files

Tags: html, css, atom-editor

I have typed the following code in atom code editor. I have a folder called ***HTML-Personal Site*** and inside it i have my ***index.html*** file and also other linked html files called ***Hobbies.html*** and ***Contact Info.html***. Inside the HTML-Personal Site folder i also have a css file called ***styles.css*** which i have linked which i have linked to the main html file(index.html) . The problem is that the changes which i am doing to my css file are only applying to my ***index.html*** file and not the other html files (which are linked to index.html).

this is how i have linked index.html to styles.css (my css file): (pls ignore the big table in the code)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Soham's Personal Site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <table cellspacing="20">
    <tr>
      <td><img src="Attack-on-titan-circle.png" alt="Attack on Titan"></td>
      <td>
        <h1>Soham dengra</h1>
        <p><em>A boy learning to code and make his <strong><a href="https://www.google.com/">1st website</a></strong>.</em></p>
        <p>I like reading  and listening to music music .</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <hr>
  <h3>Education</h3>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://nalandapublicschool.org/">Nalanda Public School</a></li>
    <li>Secondary Section</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Class 10</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>

  <hr>

  <h3>Work experience</h3>
  <table cellspacing="10">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Dates</th>
        <th>Places</th>
      </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
    <tfoot>

    </tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>2014-15</td>
      <td>Scouts and Guides</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2015-16</td>
      <td>Scouts and Guides</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <hr>

  <h3>Skills</h3>

  <table cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
      <td>Reading</td>
      <td>⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>General Knowledge</td>
      <td>⭐⭐⭐⭐</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sports</td>
      <td>⭐⭐⭐</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <hr>

  <a href="Hobbies.html">Hobbies</a><br>
  <a href="Contact Info.html">Contact Information</a>
</body>

</html>
```

this is my css file (styles.css) :

```
body {
  background-color: #EAF6F6;
}



h1 {
  color: #66BFBF;
}

h3 {
  color: #66BFBF;
}

hr {
  border-style: none;
  border-top-style: dotted;
  border-color: grey;
  border-width: 5px;
  width: 5%;
}
```

This is my other html file (Contact Info.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Contact Me</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1><em>This is my contact information.</em></h1>


  <ol>
    <li>Phone No : 123456789</li>
    <li>Email address : abcd@gmail.com</li>
    <li>Facebook : contact.facebook.com</li>
  </ol>
  <hr>
  <form class="" action="mailto:sohamdengra05@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    <label>Your Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="YourName" value=""><br>
    <label>Your Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="YourEmail" value=""><br>
    <label>Your Message:</label><br>
    <textarea name="name" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="">
  </form>



</body>

</html>
```

This is my 3rd html file ( Hobbies.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Hobbies</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>Reading</li>
    <ol type="i">
      <li>Fiction </li>
      <li>Sci-fi</li>
      <li>Fantasy</li>
      <li>Mystery</li>

    </ol>
    <li><a href="https://www.imdb.com/">Movies</a></li>
    <ol>
      <li>Sci-fi</li>
      <li>Mystery</li>
      <li>Adventure</li>
    </ol>
  </ol>


</body>

</html>
```

Someone told me that the linking problem is caused by a bug in atom and that i would need to reinstall it but then I tried running the same files in atom on another pc but still faced the same problem.
So please tell me what is going wrong with the code.I have tried solving the problem but i am not able to do it (I am a bit of a beginner in coding).Hope you are able to understand my question.
Thank you

Comment: you have to use reference `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">` into other 2 html files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">` to every files

Comment: if your are just using raw html you can't link multiple html files so you will have to ask her how she does it

Comment: sorry. i misunderstood .the instructor had also proceeded in the same way as you told. I misheard . Sorry again and thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your Contact.html file don't include the stylesheet file. You need to add    to all the files which should use that stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code from the index page to other pages.
into the head.
example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Hobbies</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>Reading</li>
    <ol type="i">
      <li>Fiction </li>
      <li>Sci-fi</li>
      <li>Fantasy</li>
      <li>Mystery</li>

    </ol>
    <li><a href="https://www.imdb.com/">Movies</a></li>
    <ol>
      <li>Sci-fi</li>
      <li>Mystery</li>
      <li>Adventure</li>
    </ol>
  </ol>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

to all the three html files